# How do I erase an element from std::vector<> by index?

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector, erase

I have a `std::vector<int>`, and I want to delete the `n`th element. How do I do that?

Example:

```cpp
std::vector<int> vec;

vec.push_back(6);
vec.push_back(-17);
vec.push_back(12);

vec.erase(???);
```

Comment: Consider using a std::deque which provides inserting and deleting at both ends.

Comment: No, don't consider using deque just because you may want to delete an element, that's really poor advice. There's a whole load of reasons why you may want to use deque or vector. It is true that deleting an element from a vector can be costly - esp if the vector is large, but there's no reason to think that a deque would be any better than a vector from the code example you just posted.

Comment: For example, if you have a graphical application where you display a "list" of things where you insert/remove things interactively, consider you run through the list 50-100 times each second to display them, and you add/remove things a few times each minute.  So implementing the "list" as a vector is probably a better option in term of total efficiency.

Comment: I recommend std::vector.erase(...), which is also my preference - you can choose to delete either a single element or a range.

Answer (score 862, accepted):

To delete a single element, you could do:

```
std::vector<int> vec;

vec.push_back(6);
vec.push_back(-17);
vec.push_back(12);

// Deletes the second element (vec[1])
vec.erase(std::next(vec.begin()));
```

Or, to delete more than one element at once:

```
// Deletes the second through third elements (vec[1], vec[2])
vec.erase(std::next(vec.begin(), 1), std::next(vec.begin(), 3));
```

Comment: Note also binary `operator+` is __not__ necessarily defined for iterators on other container types, like `list<T>::iterator` (you cannot do `list.begin() + 2` on an `std::list`, you have to use [`std::advance`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/advance/) for that)

Comment: are you stating that the "+1" is the first element myVector[0] or the actual position myVector[1]

Comment: it+1 is element with id 1, e.g container[1]. first element  is +0. See the comment below...

Comment: With advance you must save the iterator in a variable. If you use std::next you can do it in one line:   vec.erase( next(begin(vec), 123) );

Comment: Thank you to all who have answered. What are we to think of a class design when such a simple operation as deleting an element, requires one to come to StackOverflow?

Comment: what is `begin()`?, why not just `1`?

Comment: @user25 erase takes in a vector<T>::iterator, not an int. begin() is the itterator at the start of the vector, or element [0]. By adding to it, we increment it by the number of elements required to find the element we want to remove.

Comment: @Pierre because the *numerical index* of a particular element is not the primary model of access, *iterator* is. All the functions that look at elements of a container use that container's iterators. E.g. [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

Comment: @Caleth yeah, but std::vector could still provide a method for this very common use-case. Everybody bashes Qt containers, but QList for instance has removeOne() which is just a no-brainer compared to the ugliness of std::vector.

Comment: @RichardW Let's not turn beautiful `std::vector` into nightmarish `std::string`.

Comment: @Caleth Huh? Access by index (`at()` and `operator[]`) is one of the main distinctive properties of `std::vector`. It would only be consistent to also support inserting and erasing at an index.

Answer (score 477):

The `erase` method on `std::vector` is overloaded, so it's probably clearer to call

```
vec.erase(vec.begin() + index);
```

when you only want to erase a single element.

Comment: But that problem appears no matter how many elements you have.

Comment: if there's only one element, index is 0, and so you get `vec.begin()` which is valid.

Comment: I wish someone would have mentioned that `vec.erase(0)` does not work, but `vec.erase(vec.begin()+0)` (or without +0) does. Otherwise I get no matching function call, which is why I came here

Comment: @qrtLs `vec.erase(0)` may actually compile if `0` happens to be interpreted as the null pointer constant ...

Comment: @qrtLs erase() function takes iterator type as the argument; as 0 is not an iterator, it would give compiler error as no matching function call.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer as this is a solution based on index (as asked for)

Answer (score 68):

```
template <typename T>
void remove(std::vector<T>& vec, std::size_t pos)
{
    std::vector<T>::iterator it = vec.begin();
    std::advance(it, pos);
    vec.erase(it);
}
```

Comment: Max, what makes that function better than: `template <typename T> void remove(std::vector<T>& vec, size_t pos) { vec.erase(vec.begin + pos); }` I'm not saying either is better, merely asking out of personal interest and to return the best result this question could get.

Comment: @JoeyvG: Since a `vector<T>::iterator` is a random-access iterator, your version is fine and maybe a bit clearer. But the version that Max posted should work just fine if you change the container to another one that doesn't support random-access iterators

Comment: This is imo the better answer, as it applies to other container formats too. You could also use std::next().

Comment: Much better approach since it doesn't rely on the internals of the container.

Comment: std::advance is only needed if you think this will not be a vector i.e. a list. But as you've specified that here, would operator+ not be simpler ? According to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668088/advance-iterator-for-the-stdvector-stdadvance-vs-operator there is a possible gain in performance with operator+

Comment: It should be `typename std::vector<T>::iterator it = vec.begin();` or just `auto it = vec.begin();`

Answer (score 41):

The `erase` method will be used in two ways:

1. Erasing single element:

   ```
   vector.erase( vector.begin() + 3 ); // Deleting the fourth element
   ```
2. Erasing range of elements:

   ```
   vector.erase( vector.begin() + 3, vector.begin() + 5 ); // Deleting from fourth element to sixth element
   ```

Comment: This is a duplicate answer almost 7 years after the accepted answer. Please don't do this.

Comment: @AlastairG This answer is a lot shorter and clearer than the original answer, though it could technically simply be an edit instead (Such an edit might be against the wishes of the original answer's OP though)

Comment: I think we should add - it removes from 4th to 6th element excluded (6th element is not included/erased)

Answer (score 38):

Erase an element with index :

```
vec.erase(vec.begin() + index);
```

Erase an element with value:

```
vec.erase(find(vec.begin(),vec.end(),value));
```

Comment: Please make more obvious the additional insight this answer provides in comparison to other existing older and upvoted answers.

Answer (score 16):

Actually, the `erase` function works for two profiles:

- Removing a single element

  ```cpp
  iterator erase (iterator position);
  ```
- Removing a range of elements

  ```cpp
  iterator erase (iterator first, iterator last);
  ```

Since `std::vec.begin()` marks the start of container and if we want to delete the ith element in our vector, we can use:

```cpp
vec.erase(vec.begin() + index);
```

If you look closely, `vec.begin()` is just a pointer to the starting position of our vector and adding the value of `i` to it increments the pointer to the position `i`. So, we instead can access the pointer to the `i`th element with `&vec[i]`:

```cpp
vec.erase(&vec[i]); // To delete the ith element
```

Comment: -1 The last line does not compile (at least in VS2017). The code assumes that vector::iterator is implicitly constructible from a raw pointer, which is not required by the standard.

Comment: This is true especially for debug iterators

Answer (score 14):

If you have an unordered vector you can take advantage of the fact that it's unordered and use something I saw from Dan Higgins at CPPCON

```
template< typename TContainer >
static bool EraseFromUnorderedByIndex( TContainer& inContainer, size_t inIndex )
{
    if ( inIndex < inContainer.size() )
    {
        if ( inIndex != inContainer.size() - 1 )
            inContainer[inIndex] = inContainer.back();
        inContainer.pop_back();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Since the list order doesn't matter, just take the last element in the list and copy it over the top of the item you want to remove, then pop and delete the last item.

Comment: I think this is the best answer if the vector is unordered.  It does not rely on the assumption that `iterator + index` will actually give you back the iterator position at that index, which is not true of all iterable containers. It is also constant complexity instead of linear by taking advantage of the back pointer.

Comment: This totally needs to be added to the std lib as ```unordered_remove``` and ```unordered_remove_if``` … unless it has been and I missed it, which is happening more and more often these days :)

Comment: If would suggest to use move-assignment or swap instead of a copy-assignment.

Comment: `std::remove` reorders the container so that all the elements to be removed are at the end, no need to do it manually like this if you are using C++ 17.

Comment: @keith how does `std::remove` help? cppreference claims that even in C++17, all `remove` overloads require a predicate, and none take an index.

Answer (score 12):

It may seem obvious to some people, but to elaborate on the above answers:

If you are doing removal of `std::vector` elements using `erase` in a loop over the whole vector, you should process your vector in **reverse order**, that is to say using

`for (int i = v.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)`

instead of (the classical)

`for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)`

The reason is that indices are affected by `erase` so if you remove the 4-th element, then the former 5-th element is now the new 4-th element, and it won't be processed by your loop if you're doing `i++`.

Below is a simple example illustrating this where I want to remove all the odds element of an int vector;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void printVector(const vector<int> &v)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{    
    vector<int> v1, v2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        v1.push_back(i);
        v2.push_back(i);
    }

    // print v1
    cout << "v1: " << endl;
    printVector(v1);
    
    cout << endl;
    
    // print v2
    cout << "v2: " << endl;
    printVector(v2);
    
    // Erase all odd elements
    cout << "--- Erase odd elements ---" << endl;
    
    // loop with decreasing indices
    cout << "Process v2 with decreasing indices: " << endl;
    for (int i = v2.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (v2[i] % 2 != 0)
        {
            cout << "# ";
            v2.erase(v2.begin() + i);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << v2[i] << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    
    // loop with increasing indices
    cout << "Process v1 with increasing indices: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++)
    {
        if (v1[i] % 2 != 0)
        {
            cout << "# ";
            v1.erase(v1.begin() + i);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << v1[i] << " ";
        }
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
v1:
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

v2:
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
--- Erase odd elements ---
Process v2 with decreasing indices:
# 8 # 6 # 4 # 2 # 0

Process v1 with increasing indices:
0 # # # # #
```

Note that on the second version with increasing indices, even numbers are not displayed as they are skipped because of `i++`

Note also that processing the vector in reverse order, you **CAN'T** use unsigned types for indices (`for (uint8_t i = v.size() -1; ...` won't work). This because when `i` equals `0`, `i--` will overflow and be equal to `255` for `uint8_t` for example (so the loop won't stop as `i` will still be `>= 0`, and probably out of bounds of the vector).

Answer (score 6):

If you work with large vectors (size > 100,000) and want to delete lots of elements, I would recommend to do something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    vector <int> vec;
    vector <int> vec2;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20000000; i++){
        vec.push_back(i);}

    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        if(vec.at(i) %3 != 0)
            vec2.push_back(i);
    }

    vec = vec2;
    cout << vec.size() << endl;
}
```

The code takes every number in vec that can't be divided by 3 and copies it to vec2. Afterwards it copies vec2 in vec. It is pretty fast. To process 20,000,000 elements this algorithm only takes 0.8 sec!

I did the same thing with the erase-method, and it takes lots and lots of time:

```
Erase-Version (10k elements)  : 0.04 sec
Erase-Version (100k elements) : 0.6  sec
Erase-Version (1000k elements): 56   sec
Erase-Version (10000k elements): ...still calculating (>30 min)
```

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: Interesting, but not relevant to the question!

Comment: Won't a in-place algorithm faster?

Comment: that's std::remove_if (+erase)

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you read about the [**erase–remove idiom**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom). 
 For example:

```
vec.erase(vec.begin() + 1, vec.begin() + 3);
```

With this, you will erase the `n`th element of `vec` but before you erase the second element, **all** the other elements of `vec` will be shifted and the vector size will be reduced by 1. This can be a problem as you may be looping through `vec` while **its `size()` is decreasing**.

If you have problem like this the provided link suggests to use `remove` and `remove_if`.

Comment: This idiom has been obsoleted by `std::erase_if`.

Answer (score 3):

To delete an element use the following way:

```
// declaring and assigning array1 
std:vector<int> array1 {0,2,3,4};

// erasing the value in the array
array1.erase(array1.begin()+n);
```

For a **more broad overview** you can visit: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/

Comment: Consider using [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520052/whats-wrong-with-cplusplus-com), [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275760/should-we-complain-about-the-resources-linked-in-answers), etc.

Answer (score 3):

if you need to erase an element inside of a for-loop, do the following:

```
int i = 0;
while(i < vec.size()){

    if(condition)
        vec.erase(vec.begin() + i);
    else
        ++i;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**You need to use the Standard Template Library's `std::vector::erase` function.**

### Example: Deleting an element from a vector (using index)

```
// Deleting the eleventh element from vector vec
vec.erase( vec.begin() + 10 );
```

### Explanation of the above code

**`std::vector<T,Allocator>::erase` Usage:**

```
iterator erase (iterator position); // until C++11
```

```
iterator erase( const_iterator pos ); // since C++11 and until C++20
```

```
constexpr iterator erase( const_iterator pos ); // since C++20
```

Here there is a single parameter, `position` which is an iterator pointing to a single element to be removed from the vector.
Member types `iterator` and `const_iterator` are random access iterator types that point to elements.

### How it works

`erase` function does the following:

- It removes from the vector either a single element (`position`) or a range of elements (`[first, last)`).
- It reduces the container size by the number of elements removed, which are destroyed.

**Note: The iterator `pos` must be valid and dereferenceable. Thus the `end()` iterator (which is valid, but is not dereferenceable) cannot be used as a value for `pos`.**

### Return value and Complexity

The return value is an iterator pointing to the new location of the element that followed the last element that was erased by the function call. This is the container end of the operation that erased the last element in the sequence.

Member type iterator is a [`random access iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/random_access_iterator) type that points to elements.

Here, the time complexity is linear on the number of elements erased (destructions) plus the number of elements after the last element is deleted (moving).

Comment: deleting Nth index example is super helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers assume that you **always** have a signed index. Sadly, `std::vector` uses `size_type` for indexing, and `difference_type` for iterator arithmetic, so they don't work together if you have "-Wconversion" and friends enabled. This is another way to answer the question, while being able to handle both signed and unsigned:

To remove:

```
template<class T, class I, class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<I>::value>::type>
void remove(std::vector<T> &v, I index)
{
    const auto &iter = v.cbegin() + gsl::narrow_cast<typename std::vector<T>::difference_type>(index);
    v.erase(iter);
}
```

To take:

```
template<class T, class I, class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<I>::value>::type>
T take(std::vector<T> &v, I index)
{
    const auto &iter = v.cbegin() + gsl::narrow_cast<typename std::vector<T>::difference_type>(index);

    auto val = *iter;
    v.erase(iter);

    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one more way to do this if you want to delete a element by finding this with its value in vector,you just need to do this on vector.

```
vector<int> ar(n);
ar.erase(remove(ar.begin(), ar.end()), (place your value here from vector array));
```

it will remove your value from here.
thanks

Answer (score -6):

the fastest way (for programming contests by time complexity() = constant)

can erase 100M item in 1 second;

```
    vector<int> it = (vector<int>::iterator) &vec[pos];
    vec.erase(it);
```

and most readable way :
`vec.erase(vec.begin() + pos);`

Comment: This is very non-portable; it will work with libstdc++, but not libc++, and not with MSVC.  `vector<int>::iterator` is not necessarily the same as `int *`

Comment: It's disgusting, I think I'll change libstdc++ to stop it from working.