# Remove vector elements based on the index

Tags: c++, stl, vector, erase-remove-idiom

I wanted to remove the elements of the vector based on the index, say all the even indexed elements. 
I have read about the erase remove idiom but can't see how to apply it.
This is what I tried:

```
    vector<int> line;
    line.reserve(10);
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
    {
      line.push_back(i+1);
    }
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<line.size();++i)
    {
      //remove the even indexed elements
      if(i%2 == 0)
      {
        remove(line.begin(),line.end(),line[i]);
      }
    }
line.erase( line.begin(),line.end() );
```

This erases the entire vector. I was hoping to only remove the elements that had been marked by the remove algorithm.

Then I tried this

```
for(unsigned int i=0;i<line.size();++i)
    {
      //remove the even indexed elements
      if(i%2 == 0)
      {
        line.erase( remove(line.begin(),line.end(),line[i]),line.end() );
      }
    }
```

This again doesn't work as there is a problem while removing, the indices seem to shift whilst iterating over the vector.
What should be the correct approach to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Online Demo](http://codepad.org/VthyXuuK)**:

```
#include <vector> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

/*Check if Index is Even or Odd*/ 
bool is_IndexEven(int i) 
{
   static int k = 1;

   /*Handle Index 0 as special case as per choice*/
   if(k == 1)
   {
       k++;
       return false;
   } 

   if(k++ % 2)
       return true;
   else 
       return false; 
 }

int main() 
{
    using namespace std;
    int elements[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    // create a vector that holds the numbers from 0-9.
    vector<int> v(elements, elements + 10); 

    /*Display elements before removal*/    
    vector<int>::const_iterator iter = v.begin();
    cout<<"Before\n";

    for(iter;iter!= v.end();++iter)
    {
        cout<<*iter;
    }

    /*Remove_if + Erase Algorithm for one step removal*/
    v.erase( remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), is_IndexEven), v.end() ); 

    /*Display result after elements removed*/
    cout<<"\nAfter\n";
    iter = v.begin();
    for(iter;iter!= v.end();++iter)
    {
       cout<<*iter;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1. However, it looks like `remove_if` removes elements based on their values. Is this correct? What if we want to remove vector elements based on their index?

Comment: As Benjamin Lindley comments on [an analogous answer to this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122555/removing-by-index-from-a-c-vector-using-remove-if), "This makes an assumption about the order in which `remove_if` applies the predicate, which is not warranted by the standard text.".

Answer (score 10):

By going from `0` to `size`, you'll end up skipping half of the elements because the indices change as you erase the elements. Make your `for` loop go from `size()` to `0`:

```
for(unsigned int i = line.size(); i > 0; i--)
{

}
```

Comment: I hope you mean `size() - 1`?

Comment: no. that would mess up the loop if the size == 0. Whenever you're referring to the element, just go [i-1]

Comment: `for(std::vector<int>::iterator it = line.end(); it != line.begin(); --it)`?

Comment: @AusCBloke no. it's `unsigned int` meaning that `i` would actually be greater than 0 even when it's `-1==0xFFFFFFFF=4294967295` and you'd go into a near infinite loop.

Comment: @JosephH: haha woops, my bad, didn't register the `unsigned` part, just saw the `int`. +1 for that.

Comment: That wouldn't actually work for me. It'll add a few extra checks. I'm looking for an elegant way to do this.

Comment: @nikhil this _is_ the elegant way if you're sticking with `for` loops. You can always use `remove_if` as freerider mentioned

Comment: `for (unsigned int i=line.size(); i-- != 0;)` requires no `[i-1]` chicanary in every location where `i` would normally be used in the loop body.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use [remove_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/)? Use a static variable inside the function to signal the index for the current element.

Comment: In addition to the answer above, the example code in this link does exactly what you (OP) are looking for: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/

Comment: @yasouser, no it does not, the example code removes items based on the values being even or not, not their index.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to use erase-remove method to remove odd numbers from a vector. I am not sure whether you can remove elements based on the index, because remove_if() applies the predicate on the values pointed by the iterators rather than the iterator itself.

See the following :
    http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(11);
    v.push_back(22);
    v.push_back(33);
    v.push_back(44);
    v.push_back(55);
    v.push_back(66);
    v.push_back(77);
    ostream_iterator<int> printit(cout, " ");

    cout << "Before removing odd numbers" << endl;
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), printit);


    v.erase(remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
          [] (int e) { return e%2 == 1; }), v.end());

    cout << endl;
    cout << "After removing odd numbers" << endl;
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), printit);
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: "I am not sure whether you can remove elements based on the index..." that's the whole point of the question.

Answer (score 1):

An answer that generalizes not only upon the type of container to be handled but also upon the type of container that holds the indices to be removed, is given in :
[Erasing elements in stl::vector by using indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609547/erasing-elements-in-stlvector-by-using-indexes/21148808#21148808)