# How to erase from vector by iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, erase

I want to erase elements by indexes. Inside eraseIndexs function I access to begin & end iterators.When I create a vector from begin and end iterators create a new vector from them.

How to erase elements by iterators?

```
template <typename ForwardIt>
void eraseIndexs(ForwardIt& begin, ForwardIt& end, const vector<size_t>& indexs){
    using T = typename iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::value_type;
    vector<T> v(begin, end);
    for (size_t index = 0; index < indexs.size(); index++)
        v.erase(v.begin() + indexs[index] - index);
}
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122555/removing-by-index-from-a-c-vector-using-remove-if

Comment: "I want to erase elements by indexes." followed by "How to erase elements by iterators?" What do you want actually?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do. why do you try to manipulate a local variable (vector) that will fall out of scope?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I think we can assume it won't. It's good that people provide SSCCE's :)

Comment: @keyser: It does. Right there in the code.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I know. I mean in the _real_ code. I'm assuming there is such a thing since the above code does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are not erasing anything**

you are making a local `std:vector`  in your function :

```
vector<T> v(begin, end);
```

and then erasing from it

```
v.erase(v.begin() + indexs[index] - index);
```

It doesn't erase your real vector's iterator .

**If you want to erase from vector :**

you have to pass `std::vector` to your function and use `erase` member function :

```
template <typename Container>
void eraseIndexs(Container& c, const vector<size_t>& indexs){
    for (size_t index = 0; index < indexs.size(); index++)
        c.erase(c.begin() + indexs[index] - index);
}
```