# How to find a value to remove from a vector, and remove the same position from a secondary vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I have 2 vectors, for eg

```
 vector<int> set1;     // 4, 5, 2
 vector<string> set2;  // a, b, c
```

I want to find and remove `5` from `set1` and and since it's the 2nd item, remove `b` from `set2` as well.

Comment: Remember the position maybe?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35286786).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, a *vector* called `set1` or `set2` is strange. Why not use `std::set`?

Anyway, supposing that `set2` is not smaller than `set1`, a very generic solution would be to use [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) to calculate the distance between the find result and the start of `set1`. You can then just add the distance to the start of `set2`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> set1 = { 4, 5, 2 };
    std::vector<std::string> set2 = { "a", "b", "c" };

    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    // get iterator to first '5' element:
    auto const set1_iter = std::find(begin(set1), end(set1), 5);

    // how many steps does it take to go from start to the '5' element?
    auto const distance = std::distance(begin(set1), set1_iter);

    // go to same position in set2:
    auto const set2_iter = begin(set2) + distance;

    // use position to erase the element:
    set2.erase(set2_iter);

    for (auto&& element : set2)
    {
        std::cout << element << "\n";
    }
}
```

In real code, you will want to add some error handling for the case when `set2` is smaller or when 5 does not exist.

Comment: Upvoted for the style and `const` correctness! Why use rvalue ref in the output loop, not an lvalue one?

Comment: @iksemyonov: I'm still looking for a really sound C++11 guideline for range-based `for` loops with `auto`, but so far I find the `&&` version most compelling because it will always do "the right thing", regardless of whether you are dealing with `const` elements or not. I feel that the C++ community as a whole has not come to a satisfactory conclusion here. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26991393/what-does-auto-e-do-in-range-based-for-loops as a starting point to see the general confusion about this topic.

Comment: Thank you for the link! Does using stream iterators for output maybe hide this issue?

Comment: @iksemyonov: Yes. But `std::copy(begin(set2), end(set2), std::ostream_iterator<decltype(set2)::value_type>(std::cout, "\n"));` is not exactly readable code in my books.

Comment: Hmm. Must be a matter of preference then. Not so long ago I got quite the opposite impression, reading SO, that the above is how output is to be done STL "style".

Comment: @iksemyonov: I personally think that I/O and "STL"-style do not go together.

Comment: Yep, seen that POV as well in some articles, I know what you mean. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use pair like this

```
vector < pair < int,string > > set;
```

Example of push

```
set.push_back(make_pair(1,"a"));
set.push_back(make_pair(2,"b"));
set.push_back(make_pair(3,"c"));
```

And the last is your question, is how to erase said 2 and "b" from the vector. First you got to find the index by searching it.

```
for(int x = 0; x < set.size(); x++)
    if(set[x].first == 2){ //here we want delete data who have int of 2
        idx = x; //save the index at variable idx
        break;
    }
```

Ok, after we have find the index, now erase it using vector::erase. Here how to do it.

```
set.erase(set.begin()+idx);
```

There you go, hope it help.

Reading source :

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/