# Is it possible to erase elements of a std::list in a c++11 for each loop

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

I want to use the new C++11 for each loop to iterate over all elements of a list and erase certains elements. For example

```
std::list<int> myList;
myList.push_back(1); 
myList.push_back(13);
myList.push_back(9);
myList.push_back(4);

for(int element : myList) {
    if(element > 5) {
        //Do something with the element

        //erase the element
    }else{
        //Do something else with the element
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this using the for each loop or do I have to go back to iterators to achive this?

Comment: why cant you use remove_if/erase?

Comment: Or just `list::remove_if`, no iterators necessary.

Comment: @KarthikT and @BenjaminLindley: Sorry, I didn't mention in my question. I want to do some stuff with the elements that satisfy the condition and also with all others. I probably could put this into to Predicate function used by `list::remove_if`, but I find that is not very nice.

Comment: @Haatschii depending on the nature of the processing, if it isnt too performance critical, I would do it in 2 passes, cleaner that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to just do this

```
myList.erase(std::remove_if(myList.begin(), myList.end(),
    [](int& element) 
    { 
        return element > 5;
    } 
    ),myList.end());
```

or simply (courtesy Benjamin Lindley)

```
myList.remove_if(
    [](int& element) 
    { 
        return element > 5;
    } 
    );
```

Comment: shifting elements is pretty inefficient for a list

Comment: hm, nice edit :) but wait... `std::erase`? have you tried to *compile* this?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I believe you are mistaken, removal and inserting is O(1) for std::list. Shifting will happen for sequential containers such as std::vector.

Comment: @fish: `std::remove_if` doesn't remove elements, it moves or swaps them (aka shifting).

Comment: @fish: you might just try it, removing the call to (non-existent) `std::erase`. it would have been a good idea to try it before commenting.

Comment: Using a lambda function, it is not as ugly as I thought to use `remove_if`. Important to note, that I need to use `(int& element)` in order to be able to change the elements (and also prevent copys when using objects instead of ints), as Matthieu's answer points out. I think I'll go this way. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can't erase elements of standard containers in a range-based for loop over that container -- the loop itself has an iterator to the element that you're currently visiting, and erasing it would invalidate that iterator before the loop increments it.

Range-based for is defined in 6.5.4 of the standard to be equivalent to (slightly simplified):

```
for (auto __begin=begin-expr, __end=end-expr; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
    for-range-declaration = *__begin;
    statement
}
```

`begin-expr` and `end-expr` have their own lengthy definition, but in your example they are `myList.begin()` and `myList.end()` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, I don't think so. See [this SO answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360461/removing-item-from-vector-while-in-c11-range-for-loop)

> No, you can't. Range-based for is for when you need to access each
>   element of a container once.
>
> You should use the normal for loop or one of it's cousins if you need
>   to modify the container as you go along, access an element more than
>   once, or otherwise iterate in a non-linear fashion through the
>   container.