# Erase some of a vector's elements in a for-each loop without iterating the whole vector

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I have a vector and I am searching for an element in it while iterating over the vector with a for-each loop. If I find any invalid elements during the search, I would like to remove them from the vector.

Basically, I want to do something like this:

```
for (auto el : vec) {
    if (el == whatImLookingFor) {
        return el;
    } else if (isInvalid(el)) {
        vec.erase(el);
    }
}
```

I looked at some other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938838/erasing-from-a-stdvector-while-doing-a-for-each) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304950/is-it-possible-to-erase-elements-of-a-stdlist-in-a-c11-for-each-loop), but both  recommend using `std::remove_if`. That will iterate over the whole vector and remove all invalid elements, **instead of** iterating only until I find the element I'm looking for, and ignoring any elements after that.

What would be a good way to do this?

Comment: Don't you need an iterator as an argument for [std::vector<T>::erase()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) ???

Comment: The [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3938847) you linked to has a code snippet at the top which is basically what you want - just insert a check for whether the elements is the one you want, and if so `break`.

Comment: Range-for is usually not the right tool if the underlying range is to be modified.

Comment: What do you return if the element is not found?

Comment: Also see [std::vector iterator invalidation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3747691/608639). It is probably the duplicate because it deals with the invalid iterator caused by `erase`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should still use `std::remove_if`, just call `std::find` beforehand.

```
auto el = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), whatImLookingFor);
auto p = std::remove_if(vec.begin(), el, isInvalid);

// returns the iterator, not the element itself.
// if the element is not found, el will be vec.end()
return vec.erase(p, el);
```

This will usually be more efficient than removing one element at a time.

Comment: Where did `v` come from in the first line?

Answer (score 8):

I was curious about the performance of this, so I ran a [quick naive benchmark](http://quick-bench.com/y3hFI9ISFi0gGnIoqJnpsAUGt7k) comparing [Benjamin's find then partial clean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50079613) and [hnefatl's for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50079535). Benjamin's is indeed faster: **113x faster**. Impressive.

[image: Naive comparison]

But I was curious where most of the computation was going, as it was greater than the sum of `remove_if` and `find`, which are the only functions that actually iterate through the array. As it turns out, however, the `vec.erase` line in his code is actually pretty slow. This is because in `remove_if` he is cleaning the area from the start to the location of the found value, which results in a gap in the middle of the array from the invalid values. `vec.erase` must then copy the remaining values to fill the gap and finally resize the array.

I ran a third test with a full-sized `remove_if`/`vec.erase` followed by a `find`, so the gap happens at the end and no copy is necessary, just truncation. It turned out to be **about 15% faster** and leaves the whole vector clean. Note that this assumes that testing for validity is cheap. If it's more than a few simple comparisons, Benjamin's answer will win hands-down, as pointed out by Chris in the comments.

[image: Microptimization benchmark]

## The code

```
auto p = std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), isInvalid);
vec.erase(p, vec.end());
return std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), whatImLookingFor);
```

[The Benchmark](http://quick-bench.com/y3hFI9ISFi0gGnIoqJnpsAUGt7k)

Comment: Interesting online-benchmark tool (a bit like http://Godbolt.org/ but with timing instead of asm output), I wasn't aware of it.  It looks like you actually benchmarked with `clang -O3` (good), but the benchmark links come up with optimizations disabled ([ridiculous and useless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000917/c-loop-optimization-help-for-final-assignment/32001196#32001196), especially for C++ template functions that have the entire implementation as small functions calling other small functions).  The ratio is actually *bigger* with -O3 than -O0, though.

Comment: @JMerdich Good answer. In a realistic situation is possible that checking if an element is invalid could be computationally more expensive which could outweigh the faster `erase`.

Comment: Both of these algorithms need to move down all the remaining elements and then erase the empty space on the end.  The difference is that the partial clean must move all the elements after the search key and the full clean only moves the valid elements.  Suppose all the elements after the key were valid and both algorithms produced as much data?  http://quick-bench.com/SZpfwb2x0uNnI3N2grysEvTms6Y

Comment: @bipll I'm not sure where you're getting O(n^2), as my code makes 3 calls and they are all O(n) or better (`remove_if` reshuffles the items as it checks, but it's still linear). Chris makes a good point in that I assumed that `isInvalid` is cheap; Benjamin's code would be faster if it isn't.

Comment: @bipll: Um, yes? I stated that several times in the answer. However, since any solutions must iterate through the vector to fill the gap, you might as well clean it if the cleaning is cheap. I'm just saying OP should consider it as well as what he is asking for.

Answer (score 7):

This is an intuitive approach to the problem that keeps the looping structure - while it only performs a single pass, due to [repeated erasing it's likely to be less efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19297382) than a two-pass approach. For this more efficient approach, [you should use Benjamin Lindley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50079613).

---

Modifying the code in the [answer to the first link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3938847) you gave, it looks like something like this would fit your specification:

```
for (auto i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end();)
{
    if (*i == whatImLookingFor)
        return i;
    else if (isInvalid(*i))
        i = vec.erase(i);       // slow, don't use this version for real
    else
        ++i;
}
```

- If we find the element you're searching for, we return an iterator to it.
- If we find an invalid element along the way (but not after the desired element), we erase it.
- We avoid iterator invalidation by keeping the iterator returned from `erase`.

You'll still need to handle the case where the element's not found, probably by returning `vec.end()`.

Comment: Calling `std::vector::erase` multiple times within a loop is generally going to be quite inefficient. Each time it will cause all the elements after the erased item to be moved along by one element. You should prefer Benjamin Lindley's answer.

Comment: @hnefatl: My answer also ignores elements after the one being searched for.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Whoops, I missed the sneaky `el` in your second line. Neat answer, +1 from me!

Answer (score 2):

As @BenjaminLindley and @JMerdich pointed out, for the problem stated, a two-pass approach is probably simpler and more efficient.

In a realistic situation, it is possible that there is some expensive calculation that needs to be done either to determine if an element is invalid or to determine if an element is the one we are looking for:

In which case a two-pass approach becomes less desirable because it causes us to do this expensive calculation twice.

But it is possible to do a single-pass approach without calling `std::vector::erase` multiple times within the loop. It is not too hard to write `std::remove_if` yourself, then we can get it to do both checks at the same time. We still just call `std::vector::erase` once at the end:

```
std::vector<T>::iterator 
findAndRemoveInvalid(std::vector<T>& vec, U whatImLookingFor) {

  // Find first invalid element - or element you are looking for
  auto first = vec.begin();
  for(;first != vec.end(); ++first) {
    auto result = someExpensiveCalculation(*first);
    if (result == whatImLookingFor)
      return first;  
    if (isInvalid(result))
      break;
  }
  if (first == vec.end())
    return first;

  // Find subsequent valid elements - or element you are looking for
  auto it = first + 1;
  for(;it != vec.end(); it++) {
    auto result = someExpensiveCalculation(*it);
    if (result == whatImLookingFor)
      break;
    if (!isInvalid(result)) {
      *first++ = std::move(*it);  // shift valid elements to the start
      continue;
    }
  }

  // erase defunct elements and return iterator to the element
  // you are looking for, or vec.end() if not found.
  return vec.erase(first, it);
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nrpz4C0toKjhW1Fz).

It is clearly more complicated though, so measure performance first.

Answer (score 1):

If a simple loop, exited with `break` is too primitive for you, I'd suggest using `std::find()` to get an iterator to the searched element and then to use `vector.erase()`to delete the othere elements.

Comment: I think the point of OP's question is that they want to perform two operations in one pass - erasing invalid elements, then returning an element matching a predicate. This answer seems to be just about erasing the element matching the predicate.

Comment: Fixed that, the approach is basically the same, only the erased range is swapped.