# Erasing while iterating an std::list

Tags: c++, list

If I'm using an `iterator` in a `for` loop and I use `erase` on a current iteration of iterator, the for loop should continue fine and access the rest of the `list` elements?

From what I have read, this should be the case and is a primary distinguishing characteristic of `list` vs `deque` or `vector`. For my purposes, a `queue` might work but I need this behavior.

Here is the loop I am considering:

```
    std::list<Sequence>::iterator iterator;
    iterator=m_concurrents.begin();
    for (;iterator!=m_concurrents.end();++iterator){
        if (iterator->passes()){
            m_concurrents.erase(iterator);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The idiomatic way to write that loop would be:

```
for (auto i = list.begin(); i != list.end();) {
    if (condition)
        i = list.erase(i);
    else
        ++i;
}
```

You can do the same thing with a `set`, `multiset`, `map`, or `multimap`. For these containers you can erase an element without affecting the validity to any iterators to other elements. Other containers like `vector` or `deque` are not so kind. For those containers only elements before the erased iterator remain untouched. This difference is simply because `list`s store elements in individually allocated nodes. It's easy to take one link out. `vector`s are contiguous, taking one element out moves all elements after it back one position.

Your loop is broken because you erase the element at `i` on some given condition. `i` is no longer a valid iterator after that call. Your `for` loop then increments `i`, but `i` is not valid. Hell upon earth ensues. This is the exact situation that is why `erase` returns the iterator to the element after what was erased... so you can continue traversing the `list`.

You could also use [`list::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove):

```
list.remove_if([](auto& i) { return i > 10; });
```

In the lambda, return true if the element should be removed. In this example, it would remove all elements greater than 10.

Comment: in this example, you are stopping iteration once it has been erased, therefore not iterating through the list to potentially review other elements. I am interesting in iterating the whole list, and removing entries as desired. From what I understand, this is safe with a `list` but not with other containers. That is the heart of my question, sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: This will not work for non-C++11 compilers. The erase member methods only return `void` in C++03. Changing `i = list.erase(i)` to `list.erase(i++)` will fix it.

Comment: I'm confused, sorry. You are incrementing the iterator only if it is `!cheesecake`. So how does it get incremented when it *is* `cheesecake`?

Comment: ahh, i see. `i` is automatically incremented upon the return of `erase`. I see that you are using `auto` to specify `i` as an `iterator` implicitly. still does not explain why the loop in my Q is "broken". It would seem I am doing similar, just with different style.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns Dave's loop is perhaps simpler, but I don't see why yours wouldn't work also. I think your question is what happens to the iterator sequence when one of the iterator elements is erased. I don't think you've gotten that answer yet.

Comment: @Casey, you're thinking of the associative containers, which have `void Assoc::erase(Assoc::iterator)` in C++03

Comment: @JonathanWakely Hmm that was very inconsistent. Glad it was fixed. I guess the normal use case for associative containers is erasing something you just found, not during a traversal.

Comment: @Dave, the docs at the link you gave disagree with these: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/erase/.  Also, my compiler (GNU C++ 4.6.3) says erase returns void. *sigh* I can't wait until my project moves to C++11.

Comment: @AdamCrume There are 2 tabs in those docs, click the C++11 one. Also, cppreference is better, IMO.

Comment: @Dave, I know that it returns non-void in C++11.  The point is that in pre-C++11, it returns void.

Comment: @AdamCrume True for map, not for list. I linked for list. C++11 made them consistent.

Comment: @Dave: Ah, I see.  Why should C++ be consistent? </snark>

Comment: Also consider `list.erase(std::remove_if(list.begin(), list.end(), condition), list.end())`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (auto i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); ++i) {
    if (condition) {
        list.erase(i);
        --i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do that. It goes "boom" if the first element is to be erased.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use for iterator, you can use it this way, for example:

```
list<int> lst{4, 1, 2, 3, 5};

for(auto it = lst.begin(); it != lst.end();++it){
    if ((*it % 2) == 1){
        it = lst.erase(it);  erase and go to next(erase will return the next iterator)
        --it;  // as it will be add again in for, so we go back one step
    }
}

for(auto it:lst)cout<<it<<" ";
cout<<endl;  //4 2
```

But erase in `while` iterator will be more clear:

```
list<int> lst{4, 1, 2, 3, 5};

auto it = lst.begin();
while (it != lst.end()){
    if((*it % 2) == 1){
        it = lst.erase(it);// erase and go to next
    } else{
        ++it;  // go to next
    }
}

for(auto it:lst)cout<<it<<" ";
cout<<endl;  //4 2
```

You can also use member function `remove_if`：

```
list<int> lst{4, 1, 2, 3, 5};

lst.remove_if([](int a){return a % 2 == 1;});

for(auto it:lst)cout<<it<<" ";
cout<<endl;  //4 2
```

Or use `std::remove_if` conbine with `erase` funtion:

```
list<int> lst{4, 1, 2, 3, 5};

lst.erase(std::remove_if(lst.begin(), lst.end(), [](int a){
    return a % 2 == 1;
}), lst.end());

for(auto it:lst)cout<<it<<" ";
cout<<endl;  //4 2
```

You can also reference to this question:
[Removing item from vector, while in C++11 range 'for' loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51576626/6329006)