# how to erase from vector in range-based loop?

Tags: c++11, vector

I simply wanna erase the specified element in the range-based loop:

```
vector<int> vec = { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
for (auto & i:vec)
{
    if (i>5)
    vec.erase(&i);
}
```

what's wrong?

Comment: Well it doesn't compile, let's begin there!

Comment: @alejandro okay! you tell me a way to make it compile  :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing item from vector, while in c++11 range for loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360461/removing-item-from-vector-while-in-c11-range-for-loop)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can't erase elements by value on a `std::vector`, and since range-based loop expose directly values your code doesn't make sense (`vec.erase(&i)`).

The main problem is that a `std::vector` invalidates its iterators when you erase an element.

So since the range-based loop is basically implemented as

```
auto begin = vec.begin();
auto end = vec.end()
for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
  ..
}
```

Then erasing a value would invalidate `it` and break the successive iterations.

If you really want to remove an element while iterating you must take care of updating the iterator correctly:

```
for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); /* NOTHING */)
{
  if ((*it) > 5)
    it = vec.erase(it);
  else
    ++it;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Removing elements from a vector that you're iterating over is generally a bad idea. In your case you're most likely skipping the 7. A much better way would be using [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) for it:

```
vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                          [](const int& i){ return i > 5; }),
           vec.end());
```

`std::remove` shift the elements that should be removed to the end of the container and returns an iterator to the first of those elements. You only got to erase those elements up to the end then.

Comment: We now have [`std::experimental::erase_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/vector/erase_if).

Answer (score 6):

It's quite simple: don't use a range-based loop. These loops are intended as a concise form for *sequentially iterating over all the **values** in a container.* If you want something more complicated (such as erasing or generally access to iterators), do it the explicit way:

```
for (auto it = begin(vec); it != end(vec);) {
  if (*it > 5)
    it = vec.erase(it);
  else
    ++it;
}
```

Comment: vec out of range!

Comment: @ifooi Er, what? Can you elaborate?

Comment: for (const auto &i : vec)
  std::cout<<vec[i]<<" "<< std::endl;

Comment: Sorry; I was not correct and mess my code with this

Answer (score 1):

Actually it IS *technically* possible, and works in both MSVC & GCC. But it is inadvisable as it produces warning
`"C++20-style initializer statement in a range-based 'for' statement is nonstandard in this mode (3230)"`
This is probably because its ambigous whether there is an internal duplicate iterator generated by the ranged expression `auto& i: ints`, so which iterator is checked in the implied `!=ints.end()`?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct Int {
   Int(int i) : i(i) {} 
   ~Int(){ i = -i; }
   int i;
};

int  main() {
    vector<Int> ints;//{0,1,2,3,4};
    for (int i = 0; i<5; ++i)
      ints.emplace_back(Int(i));

    for (auto it = ints.begin();  auto& i: ints) { // requires C++20 ("ranged-based for with initializer")
      if (it->i == 3 || it->i == 2)
          ints.erase(it--); // Decrement after erasing a single element, and it preserves the iterator
       ++it;
    }
    for_each(
              ints.cbegin(),
              ints.cend(),
              [] (Int i) {cout << i.i << " ";} 
              );
   // outputs 0 1 4
}
```