# Removing more than one element from an array and creating a dynamic array c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm still new to c++ so this is a learning process for me. Also i know that i should initially use a vector to do this but i have an exercise that specifies an array so i'm trying to write a function that removes all duplicate elements in an array but i receive the error

> C2100: illegal indirection

if someone could point me in the right direction

```
int main()
{       
    int *t;
    int removel[9] = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, };
    t = removeAll(removel, 9, 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        cout << t[i] << " ";
}

int* removeAll(int list[], int listlength, int removeitem)
{
    int count = 0;
    int* list2;
    int removeindex;
    int length;
    int tempindex;

    for (int i = 0; i < listlength; i++)
    {
        if (removeitem == list[i])
            count++;
    }

    length =  listlength - (count + 1);
    list2 = new int[length];
    int j;
    while (j<=length)
    {
        remove_if(list[0], list[listlength - 1], removeitem);

        for (j = 0; j < length; j++)
            if (list[j] == NULL)// not sure what the remove_if func puts inplace of the removed element
                continue;
            else
                list2[j] = list[j];
    }
    return list2;

}
```

Comment: #1 Don't declare your variables before you need them.

Comment: Use vectors. I don not see a reason why you would want to use array. And Array's are fixed size.

Comment: its for an exercise for the textbook i'm using, just trying to learn how to accomplish this task.

Comment: And after having switched to vectors, consider this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384571/is-there-a-better-alternative-to-stdremove-if-to-remove-elements-from-a-vector

Comment: Ok, #2 Format your code, you want to be able to read it. #3 `j` is not being initialized. #4 Read the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) #5 Think about the algorithm.

Comment: You can't really remove stuff from an array. Best you can do is replace it with something else. In this case you probably want to use the value after the value you want gone. And that means you have to replace the value after with the value after it. etc... Don't forget to update the amount of the array being used when you do this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstable you should calculate `length` like `listlength - count`, not `listlength - (count + 1)`.
Then, after `list2 = new int[length];` you should copy elements which are different with `removeitem` and skip other ones. You can do it like this

```
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listlength; i++) {
        if (removeitem == list[i])
            continue;
        list2[j] = list[i];
        j++;
    }
```

and return successfully created `list2`. But you should also know its size. You can do it by creating `int tSize` in main and pass it to `removeAll` by link. `removeAll` will change its value to `length`. So add `int & list2size` to the parameters list of `removeAll` and write `list2size = length;` before returning `list2`. Finally, when printing `t`, change `i < 8` to `i < tSize`.

If you do all this program will work right but don't forget about formatting.