# C++: Template and Lambda

Tags: c++

Is it common to use something like the following in C++?

```
template <typename T> function<void(vector<T> &)> filter1 = [ ] (vector<T> &vec){
    int count = 0;
    for (T t : vec){
        if ( t.cost < 500 )
            vec.erase(vec.begin()+count);
        count++;
    }
};

template <typename T> void discount(float p, vector<T> &vec){
    filter1<T>(vec);
    int count = 0;
    for (T t : vec) {
        t.cost = t.cost - t.cost * p;
        vec.erase(vec.begin() + count);
        vec.emplace(vec.begin() + count, t);
        count++;
    }
```

btw I'm calling it tembda, cause its a mixture of Template and Lambda.

Comment: You could `remove_if` anyway (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384571/is-there-a-better-alternative-to-stdremove-if-to-remove-elements-from-a-vector) and why only take vectors? You could be more general than that

Comment: BTW, your lambda invokes UB.

Comment: `vec.erase(vec.begin() + count); vec.emplace(vec.begin() + count, t);` did you simply means `for(T& t : vec)` and get rid of those lines.

Comment: No that's just horrible c++, plus it is wrong (erase in range-based for is ub. You need to use iterator-based iteration and assign the return value of erase to the iterator).

Comment: @Jarod42 I wanted to but it somehow is not updating the value.

Comment: Idioms come about because they have a good underlying reason. What's your reason for doing this?

Comment: Here is a [Demo](https://ideone.com/JXJnQf). If you still have an issue, provide problematic code in other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Template lambdas will be a part of C++20, but your intent was common enough to include in C++14.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

C++14 supports this via `auto` instead of `<typename T>`:

```
auto filter_out_low_prices = [] (auto& vec) {
    auto predicate = [](const auto& t){ return t.cost < 500.00; };
    vec.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), predicate),
            std::end(vec));
};

template <class V>
void discount(const float p, V& vec){
    filter_out_low_prices(vec);
    for (auto& t : vec)
        t.cost = t.cost - t.cost * p;
}
```

This avoids the use of `std::function` to be lightweight, as Vittorio Romeo suggested. It also uses `remove_if` to avoid undefined behavior and is not limited to `std::vector`, as doctorlove suggested.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it common to use something like the following in C++?

No.

Firstly, `std::function` is a heavyweight abstraction which unnecessarily degrades the performance of your code in this case. Secondly, there's no advantage in using a lambda expression here over a simple template function - you are just going to confuse whoever reads your code.

Comment: It could be an advantage to have a *generic lambda*, though - these are much easier to pass to generic algorithms than specific specializations of template functions.