# Erasing many vector elements while going through it with 'auto'

Tags: c++, vector, auto, erase

Let's say that I have `vector` of pairs, where each `pair` corresponds to indexes (row and column) of certain matrix I am working on

```
using namespace std;
vector<pair<int, int>> vec;
```

I wanted to, using `auto`, go through the whole vector and delete at once all the pairs that fulfill certain conditions, for example something like

```
for (auto& x : vec) {
    if (x.first == x.second) {
        vec.erase(x); 
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work, as I suppose `vec.erase()` should have an iterator as an argument and `x` is actually a `pair` that is an element of vector `vec`, not iterator. I tried to modify it in few ways, but I am not sure how going through container elements with `auto` exactly works and how can I fix this.

Can I easily modify the code above to make it work and to erase multiple elements of vector, while going through it with `auto`? Or I should modify my approach?

For now it's just a vector of pairs, but it will be much worse later on, so I would like to use `auto` for simplicity.

Comment: Confirming your supposition: [Removing item from vector, while in C++11 range 'for' loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360461/removing-item-from-vector-while-in-c11-range-for-loop)

Answer (score 5):

`vector::erase()` invalidates any outstanding iterators, including the one your range based for loop is using. Use `std::remove_if()`:

```
vec.erase(
    std::remove_if(
        vec.begin(),
        vec.end(),
        [](const pair<int,int> &xx) { return xx.first == xx.second; }
    ), vec.end()
);
```

`std::remove_if()` swaps the elements to the end of the vector and then you can safely erase them.

Comment: Yup missed it, fixed.

Comment: std::erase_if(vec, [](pair<int,int> xx) { return xx.first == xx.second; }); 
  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2 is in C++20!

Comment: @MooingDuck If he can use c++20

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer something like this:

```
  pair<int, int> pair = nullptr;
  auto iter = vec.begin();
    while(iter != vec.end()){
        pair = (*iter);
        if(pair.first == pair.second){
            iter = this->vec.erase(iter);
        }else{
            ++iter;
        }
    }
```