# std::vector > v.erase(&v[1]); not found

Tags: c++, vector

To remove an elements from a vector, we can use

```
v.erase(v.begin() + 1); // remove 2nd
```

Also I found a sentence as follows in some posts on this site (SO) (e.g [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875103/how-to-erase-element-from-stdvector-by-index)).

```
v.erase(&v[1]);
```

However, when I try to use the 2nd sentence, the compiler says "error: no matching function for call to std::vector)...

http://ideone.com/UZJaEK

Is the 2nd sentence usable only on some limited environment?

Comment: `erase()` takes an iterator. `v.erase(&v[1]);` isn't valid unless the vector's iterator happens to be a pointer. Where did you find it?

Comment: The actual question is probably: why is pointer to element not implicitly converted to iterator to element here?

Comment: @zenith Catching misuses of this sort is reason enough, IMO.

Comment: @T.C. I found it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875103/how-to-erase-element-from-stdvector-by-index

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`erase()` takes an iterator, not a pointer.

For `std::vector`, it happens that a pointer is a valid way to implement its iterator, so the second form may compile in an implementation that uses a pointer as the iterator. Such uses would be utterly unportable, of course.

Modern implementations usually use a separate type for iterators, in which case the second version will not compile. Using a separate type permits better error-checking, both at compile time (e.g., catching an accidental mix-up of a `std::string`'s iterator and a `std::vector<char>`'s), and at run time (for debug mode).

Comment: FWIW, there's a ton of code out there written with Visual Studio 6.0 that uses the pointer instead of the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/), there is no such overload for `vector::erase`.

Perhaps, you were looking for [`std::remove`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove/) instead.

**Quoted :**

> Transforms the range [first,last) into a range with all the elements that compare equal to val removed, and returns an iterator to the new end of that range.

Comment: cplusplus.com is not an "official source" of anything.