# C++ error: no match for call to '(std::list<int>) (int&)'

Tags: c++

I have a piece of script to count the highest possible sum of list elements while retaining the pattern: higher-lower-higher-lower-higher etc.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n=0;
    bool g = false;
    int d = 1000000;
    list<int> a(d,0);
    int b;

    for (int x=0; x<n; x++) {  //load the list elements
        scanf("%d", &b);
        a.push_back(b);
    }

    for (int i=0; a(n) == a(n+1); i++) {
        a.remove(n+1);  //this is to remove any (consecutive) duplicates
    }


    if (a(n) > a(n+1)) {   
        g = false;
    } else {
        g = true;
    }


while (n+1 < d) {
    if (g) {
        if (!(a(n) < a(n+1))) {
            a.remove(n+1);
            continue;
        } else {
            n = n+1;
            g = !g;
            continue;
        }
    } else {
        if (!(a(n) > a(n+1))) {
            a.remove(n+1);
        } else {
            n = n+1;
            g = !g;
            continue;
        }
    }
}
long long sum = 0 ;
for (int i = 0 ; i < a.count(); i++) {
   sum += a(i);
}

printf("%lld ", sum);

return 0;
}
```

However, at compilation attempt it throws `no match for call to '(std::list<int>) (int&)'` everywhere where I am trying to compare list elements.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: cmon people - why the downvote. OP supplies the complete code, the slightly obscure error message (but supplies it). What more can we ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a(n)` means calling the function call operator `std::list::operator()(int&)` with `n` as its argument. The error `no match for call to '(std::list<int>) (int&)'` is because `std::list` doesn't have a call operator.

A list does not support random access unlike a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) which have `operator[]` for random access. Using a vector, the random access element `n` of vector `a` becomes `a[n]`.

To traverse through a list, you use list [iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/BidirectionalIterator/)s. Use [`std::list::begin`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/begin/) to get the iterator to first element. To traverse, use assignment, increment (`++`) and decrement (`--`) operators. To access the value of the element, use dereference operator (`*`).

Answer (score 3):

`a(n)` is not valid.  `std::list` does not have a call operator (or a subscript operator, which is what I assume you intended to use).  `std::list` does not provide random access.

If you need random access, use a container that provides it, such as `std::vector`.  Then you can access items using `a[n]` notation.

Comment: If using vector you must also account for the lack of a `remove` function. The OP seems to be trying to use `remove` to remove by index, but it removes based on [value](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove). Instead they could to use `erase` to remove by iterator (relevant [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875103/how-do-i-erase-an-element-from-stdvector-by-index)). The performance will be horrible since it will be shifting elements around the vector on each erase call.

Comment: we need a `SO says "use std::vector<>"` tee shirt or mug