# How can I erase/delete vector of class objects according to some Values

Tags: c++, algorithm, class, c++11, stdvector

P S :  May be this question has already been asked but I tried a lot and also I'm not using the pointer with vector. If the solution is that, please tell me how to use pointer here.

*My Question*: I'm creating a vector of `Car` class instances and used `getter` and `setter` methods to retrieving and pushing new records inside it. Even I'm editing that records also but **I don't know how to delete particular record!** I have put the code in comments which I tried by myself. could someone help me to *remove/erase* the particular record/ instance of the class, from this vector?

Thanks in advance.

### Car.cpp

```
#include "Car.h"
#include "global.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
int cid =1;

string Name;
float Price;

//In this function I want to delete the records
void deleteCarVector( vector<Car>& newAllCar)
{
    int id;
    cout << "\n\t\t Please Enter the Id of Car to Delete Car Details :  ";
    cin >> id;
    //replace (newAllCar.begin(), newAllCar.end(),"a","b");

    unsigned int size = newAllCar.size();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(newAllCar[i].getId() == id)
        {
            cout << "Current Car Name : "<<newAllCar[i].getName() << "\n";

            // Here Exactly the problem!
            // delete newAllCar[i];
            // newAllCar.erase(newAllCar[i].newName);
            // newAllCar.erase(remove(newAllCar.begin(),newAllCar.end(),newAllCar.at(i).getId()));
        }
    }
    printCarVector(newAllCar);
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: `newAllCar.erase(i);` should do the trick.  Good luck!

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875103/how-do-i-erase-an-element-from-stdvector-by-index#875109  OP didn't specify many details so any answer would have to be for the general case, which is already covered in the other question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I erase an element from std::vector<> by index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875103/how-do-i-erase-an-element-from-stdvector-by-index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [...]How can I **"remove/erase"**
> the particular record from vector class object?

You have your  answer in your question itself: you need [erase–remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) to remove the `Car` objects from your `std::vector<Car>`, according to the key/id you provide.

```
carVec.erase(std::remove_if(carVec.begin(), carVec.end()
     , [&id_to_delete](const Car& ele) {
            return ele.getnewId() == id_to_delete;
     }), 
     carVec.end()
);
```

[Live Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4j541bdvb)

---

**[c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) Updates**

C++20 ensures a uniform container erasure semantics for [all standard containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/lib_extensions_2#Uniform_container_erasure).
Using [`std::erase_if (std::vector)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/vector/erase_if), the OP's code would look like:

```
std::erase_if(carVec, [&id_to_delete](const auto& ele) { 
    return ele.getnewId() == id_to_delete;
});
```

[Live Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/s13axhaTb)

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like below if you don't want to use lambda functions

```
void deleteCarVector( vector<Car>& newAllCar)
{
    int id;
    cout<<" \n\t\t Please Enter the Id of Car to Delete Car Details :  ";
    cin>>id;

    auto carItr = newAllCar.begin();

    while(carItr != newAllCar.end())
    {
        if((*carItr)->getId==id)
        {
            delete *carItr;
            newAllCar.erase(carItr);
            break;
        }
        carItr++;
    }

    printCarVector(newAllCar);

    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Can I talk you into replacing the `while`all of the iterator work with a range-based `for`?

Comment: There are different ways of coding you can use range based for with little tweeks

Comment: Its giving me the pointer error...

Comment: what is the error that you are getting