# Error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<Movie>::erase(size_t&)'

Tags: c++, vector

I am currently learning C++ / making a simple movie database. I use classes and I have a method `Delete Movie`. Unfortunately, when I try to delete object `Movie` from a vector `database`, there's this error.

```
        for (size_t num {}; num < database.size(); ++num) 
            if ((database.at(num)).getname() == name) {
                database.erase(num); // <--- error here
                return true;
            }
```

Can someone hopefully tell me, what am I making wrong?
If you need more information, I can send the whole file.

Comment: Because [erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) accepts `iterator` as an argument, not `size_t`. For example `database.begin() + i`

Comment: dupe of [How do I erase an element from std::vector<> by index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875103/how-do-i-erase-an-element-from-stdvector-by-index)

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`erase` accepts iterator as said pptaszni

Replace your `for` code by this:

```
auto it = std::remove_if(database.begin(), database.end(), [&name](const Movie& item) -> bool { return item.getname() == name; });
database.erase(it, database.end());
```

Or change just 1 line (`database.erase(num)`) like this:

```
database.erase(database.begin() + num);
```

Comment: It opens a very big file with loads of code? (i'm using codelite) This file is full of errors for some reason. Thanks for help, but I found a workaround

Comment: Thanks, found some other bugs in the class, fixed them and used your solution and worked!